# Unlock screen programmatically with protected pin

Tags: android, screen, unlock

I want to unlock screen with protected pin code
I use

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock keyguardLock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
```

it shows the screen where I have to us my pin code to unlock
after unlocking I can see my activity

How can I unlock screen with protected pin code?